# Opening specific components through onClick event - REACT.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some data coming from Firebase and I am printing them into the app as lists. However, at first I just want to print a header for each list and when clicking on these headers their specific lists must be shown.

I am able to hide and show the lists by clicking, but this is happening for all lists and not only for the target one.

What I am doing is the classic way, to set a state as `false` (open) and make it toggles after a click. The component is shown if `open` is true and hidden if it is false. The `onClick` function is in `Clientes`, the first child.

I have a container based on class and two functional components.

To be more specific, the container just receive the data and send it to the `Clientes` component as an object of arrays. Each array is a list and for each one of them an `Orcamentos` component is created, lastly all items of each list are rendered inside of its respective `Orcamentos`.

How could I make just the target list opens after a click?

[image]

*Container ClientesControls:

```
class ClientesControls extends Component {

state = {
    clientes: null,
    retorno: false,
    open: false
}

openOrcamentosHandler = () => {

    let open = this.state.open;

    this.setState({open: !open})

}

componentDidMount() {

    axios.get('/clientes.json')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({clientes: res.data, retorno: true})     
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))

}

render() {

    let inserirClientes = <div>Carregando...</div>

    if (this.state.retorno) {

        inserirClientes = (
            Object.keys(this.state.clientes)
                .map(key => <Clientes 
                                key={Math.random()} 
                                clienteInfo={this.state.clientes[key]} 
                                open={this.state.open} 
                                openHandler={this.openOrcamentosHandler}  
                            />)
        )
    }


    return (
        <div>
            { inserirClientes }
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

*Child Clientes:

```
const clientes = props => {

return (
    <div>

        {
            Object.keys(props.clienteInfo)
                .map(key => {
                   return (
                    <div key={Math.random()} onClick={props.openHandler}>
                        <Orcamentos orcamentosInfo={props.clienteInfo[key]} open={props.open}/>
                    </div>
                )})
        }
    </div>
  );
};
```

*Child Orcamentos:

```
const orcamentos = props => {

let nome = Object.keys(props.orcamentosInfo)
                .map(k => props.orcamentosInfo[k].nomeCliente);

return (

    <div>
        <h4>{nome[0]}</h4>
        {
            Object.keys(props.orcamentosInfo)
                .map(k => <p key={Math.random()} >{ props.open ? props.orcamentosInfo[k].data : null}</p>)
        }

    </div>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child `Orcamentos` components need to control their own `open` state. The way you have structured it they are both taking the same state as a prop from the parent `ClientesControls`, and clicking either child component refers to the same handler which updates that state, so of course they are both being activated.

```
const orcamentos = props => {

const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

let nome = Object.keys(props.orcamentosInfo)
                .map(k => props.orcamentosInfo[k].nomeCliente);

return (

    <div onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        <h4>{nome[0]}</h4>
        {
            Object.keys(props.orcamentosInfo)
                .map(k => <p key={Math.random()} >{ open ? props.orcamentosInfo[k].data : null}</p>)
        }

    </div>

  );
}
```